# Including JavaScript/jQuery libraries in .js functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, video

I'm trying to generate a token (partially random base 64 encoded string with a certain formatting) for use in a video chat application. To accomplish this, I am using Parse Cloud Code on my backend. I basically deploy a .js file that runs my server side scripts. The code I have now is below. I've been getting error code 141: "Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined" and another error saying that '$' is not defined. I suspect I am doing something like including jQuery wrong - probably something extremely noobish. Any ideas?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("generateToken", function(request, response) {
    var script1 = document.createElement('script');
    script1.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js';
    script1.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script1);
    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.src = 'https://raw.github.com/carlo/jquery-base64/master/   jquery.base64.min.js';
    script2.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script2);
    var script3 = document.createElement('script');
    script3.src = 'http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js';
    script3.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script3);
    var secondsInDay = 86400;

    // Credentials - leaving these out for security purposes
    var apiKey = <apiKey>;
    var secret = <secret>;
    var sessionId = request.params.sid;

    // Token Params
    var timeNow = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
    var expire = timeNow+secondsInDay;
    var role = "publisher";
    var data = "whatever";

    // Calculation
    data = escape(data);
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
    var dataString = "session_id="+sessionId+"&create_time="+timeNow+"&expire_time="+expire+"&role="+role+"&connection_data="+data+"&nonce="+rand;

    // Encryption
    var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA1, secret);
    hmac.update( dataString );
    hash = hmac.finalize();

    preCoded = "partner_id="+apiKey+"&sig="+hash+":"+dataString;
    token = "T1=="+$.base64.encode( preCoded );
    // Token Achieved. The End

    response.success(token);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *Cloud Code* does not operate on a DOM. It is basically server-side-scripting just with JavaScript instead of "the usual" languages.

Comment: "`document` not defined" should not happen when executing the code in a browser. Where exactly do you get that?

Comment: You seem to load the scripts asynchronously and in parallel, not checking for anything to be loaded in the right order or to be loaded at all. Likely this is where your "jQuery not defined" error stems from

Comment: [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: @Bergi - I'm deploying it using Parse Cloud Code and running it from the command line on my MacBook. Also I'm new to JavaScript/jQuery so I could be going about this all wrong - how would I make sure they are loaded in the right order?

Comment: @nickd717 try to use http://yepnopejs.com/ its a best way to load js correctly

Answer (score 0):

"document not defined" is generally a tell tale sign generally running a web worker. If you want to access the document don't use a webworker. This is because there should be only one thread accessing document so as to not cause clashes.